# Qt4 C++ Resize window, preserve square form

Tags: c++, layout, qt4, window-resize

I want to preserve the window aspect ratio when resizing it.

So the window should always have same width and height.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to answer for a similar question [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21329-keeping-a-widget-to-be-square). You have to re-implement resizeEvent(). If you do so, make sure your implementation does not have possible recursion problems.